# Как получить ip клиента?

Tags: nginx, docker

Использую laravel, nginx, docker. В одном запросе нужно определить ip адрес клиента, который делает запрос. Мой ip адресс  95.28.212.80. Как его достать в коде? Пробовал:

```
dd(request()->ip());
dd(request()->getClientIp());
dd($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

везде приходит одинаковое значение: 172.17.0.1.
Пробовал в конфигурации nginx добавить:

```
fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
```

Не помогло.
docker-compose.yaml:

```
doorphone-nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: doorphone-nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ${NGINX_CONF}:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ${BACKEND_APP}:/var/www
      - ${NGINX_LOGS}:/var/log/nginx
      - ${NGINX_HTML}:/usr/share/nginx/html
    links:
      - doorphone-php

  doorphone-php:
    build: ./php
    container_name: doorphone-php-fpm
    volumes:
      - ${BACKEND_APP}:/var/www
    links:
      - doorphone-db
  
  doorphone-db:
  ...
```

Comment: Надо смотреть как у вас сеть настроена

Comment: в теории docker использует iptables и masquerade, чтобы роутить пакеты в контейнер, поэтому вы реальный ip и не увидете, даже с правильными настройками, можно попробовать запускать nginx на host сети или вручную настроить iptables